# how to prevent a new user from login until they verify their email in firebase swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

when user register by email they get validation link to the email they provided for users to verify it. I want users who did not validate their email not be able to login or go to main screen till they verify their email. here is my code.

```
      @IBAction func emailRegisterButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

      if emailTextField.text != "" && nameTextField.text != "" && lastnameTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {

        FUser.registerUserwith(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, firstName: nameTextField.text!, lastName: lastnameTextField.text!, completion: {(error) in

            if error != nil {

                print (" Error registering user with email: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
                // ...
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("please validate your email")
            }

        })

    }
 }

      @IBAction func loginVC(_ sender: Any) {


        if ( email is not verified << Code here ) {

            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("please verify your email ")

        } else {

         go to main app or (login) 

      }

   }
```

Comment: The `User` object has `isEmailValid` property. You can simply use to check the user is validated or not.

Comment: Similarly, you can restrict access to database data and other features of Firebase using security rules. The developer needs to obtain a credential in order to complete email verification, but obtaining a credential doesn't mean they can access your app. You enforce that part.